# check if database exists AND current login can access

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I know I can check if a database exists using...

`SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'database_name'`

or...

`SELECT DB_ID('database_name')`

This check can be performed regardless of whether the current login has access to `database_name`.  If the current login does not have access, for instance, then this statement...

`USE database_name`

...will understandably fail with this message:

`The server principal "login_name" is not able to access the database "database_name" under the current security context.`

What I want is a query to tell me if the current login can access the current database.  I tried wrapping in a try catch...

```
begin try
    use database_name;
end try
begin catch
    select 'cannot access database_name'
end catch
```

... but that yields the same error as above, without even getting to the catch.  This was surprising to me -- I expected to get the custom message back.  Maybe you cannot have `USE` statements inside try catch blocks, but in any event, the try..catch sort of seems like a hack.

So is there a query to return only the databases that can be accessed by the current login?  I want to use this within an SSIS package to determine if a database exists **and** can be accessed before continuing.  As it is written now (using `IF EXISTS...`), the Execute SQL Task returns true, then the following step fails.  I would much rather the Execute SQL Task returns false, and the following step is not even executed.

For reference, the login I am using is only assigned to the 'public' server role.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try:

```
Select HAS_DBACCESS('YourDatabaseNameHere')
```

If this returns 1, the login has access.  0 means no access. NULL means the database does not exist.