# SSIS conditionally import if source is available

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am new to SSIS.  I have a SSIS package that imports a table from a different SQL Server to mine.  I created the package using the import wizard, but I understand how to open and edit using VisualStudio.  The basic package drops the original table first, creates the new table then imports the data.  I do this daily.

My problem is sometimes the other database isn't available.  I don't know there is a problem until after the table drop.  I need to know if there is a simple (enough for me) way to check the other table availability before I drop my current copy.  That way I keep my most recent data if the new data isn't available.

I thought I could import to a temp table, then check it's row count and if 0 stop there.  Or somehow check the other server first before dropping, but I don't know how to do either.  Grateful for some pointers.

Edit: Need help figuring out how to do it in SSIS as well as how to do it in general.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check if database exists AND current login can access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553515/check-if-database-exists-and-current-login-can-access)

Comment: read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/has-dbaccess-transact-sql you can add that in ssis, take the value it returns and then proceed if it is online else fail safely.

Comment: Thanks Tanner.  It's the detail on this part I'm fuzzy about:  "take the value it returns and then proceed if it is online else fail safely".  I gather from Kyle's reply if it fails (returns 1?) then the package will stop there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easy enough to accomplish. You have to check for other database tables before dropping is a simple command and here that is:

Pulled the query from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887011/how-to-drop-a-table-if-it-exists-in-sql-server)

**Permanent Table**

`IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Scores', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
 DROP TABLE dbo.Scores;`

**Temporary Table**

`IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#T', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #T;`

That will allow you to delete if the other exists.

Comment: Thanks.  That helps, but 2 follow-up's: 1) How to I format the database name to the other server?  and 2) how do I build this in the SSIS package?  Not sure how to do an If in the SSIS package and not go to the next step.  I do know how to add a SQL statement and tie it to the next task.

Comment: @shorton did you check the link I sent you on the question?

Comment: Right now I have a "Execute SQL Task" where the table is dropped, then a "Preparation SQL Task" where the new table is created, then the "data Flow Task" that does the import.  In the SSIS Toolbox I don't know what to choose to allow a branch to stop.

Comment: I would suggest creating a stored procedure for this call. In that stored procedure you will have to create a linked server to the other database. How to accomplish this is to leverage the script component tool. You will execute the statement and proceed forward. Does that cover enough? I am happy to provide more details!

Comment: @tanner, yes, I did.  If the answer is there I didn't get it, sorry.

Comment: @KylePearson Is there no way without a linked server?  Figured surely there was a way to put an "if source does not exists then stop" in SSIS flow.  No?

Comment: @shorton you could do a simple query or have it validate metadata for that table and if it doesn't exist it will fail. You could also write that statement in the ssis package and have a data source for the server. That way no linked server is needed. We just enforce using stored procs when we can,

Comment: @shorton also if this works please mark this as an answer.

Comment: I did as you suggested.  I just set up a "Execute SQL Task" with a simple select first column, first row query.  If it failed the next step didn't appear to execute.  That accomplishes what I need.  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you both for the help.

Comment: Changed query to select HAS_ACCESS(... per Tanner's suggestion. Works, too.  Seems to make more sense for what it's doing.  Thanks again.